# Minio: how to force users to change their pwd when first connected

Tags: passwords, settings, policy, minio

We're using Minio Storage and it's a great tool.
But, we want to make users to change their password when they're connected for their first time.
So could it be possible ? If yes, then how to do it ?
Many thx in advance
Yan

I've tried to find some policy settings but without any result.

Answer (score 0):

you can use mc admin user add command to change the pwd. Adding user and chaning password can be done with this command. If you wish to change pwd via console you can login and go to Access keys tab and click on change password. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I do appreciate your help. Yes, they can change their pwd. But I want to make users  change their password when they're first connected in line with  our password security policy.